# Execute a ping to an address using Lua io.popen, non blocking if ping times out

Tags: lua, ping, blocking

Have found on this excellent pages the following function:

```
function os.capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
  local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
  f:close()
  if raw then return s end
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
  return s
end
```

If I execute this function with cmd = "ping myknowngoodip -c 1" then all is good, its immediately coming back with the result.

But if a ping times out (server down or so) it block for at least 5 second the whole program

Possible solutions for me:

- Use coroutines (but how to design them properly to get it working?)
- Use something to detect if the file gets written or a write lock is on it (how do I do that?)

Target is that I do receive over copas (http://keplerproject.github.io/copas/) "lookup" requests to ping different IPs and report back if the IP is alive or not. Copas is up and running, works so far

Many thanks for all your help

Comment: Separate thread with dedicated Lua VM in it?

Answer (score 1):

io.popen is not going to work with copas. Copas is for sockets, not pipes.

The quickest solution is to use polling; do e.g.:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local waitTime, sleepTime = 5, 0.1
local endT = os.time() + waitTime
local result
os.capture("ping myknowngoodip -c 1 > myoutfile")
while os.time() <= endT do
    local pcall_ok, fHand = pcall(io.open, "myoutfile", "r")
    if pcall_ok then
        result = assert(fHand:read("*all"))
        assert(fHand:close())
    end
    socket.sleep(sleepTime)
end
if result then
    -- Success!
else
    -- Error :(
end
```

Another possibility is a separate thread; [LuaLanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/) is the best multithreading toolkit out there, but also the biggest in terms of memory consumption. This is somewhat more involved, however.

Another option is to implement your own ping over sockets with Copas or [LOOP's SocketScheduler](http://loop.luaforge.net/library/thread/SocketScheduler.html) (recommended, it's much better than Copas); this would be async to start with. LOOP.SocketScheduler is also a great coroutine management framework, useful for all sorts of things, and can be used with the code sampled above (replace socket.sleep with scheduler:sleep, and run the code in a newly created and registered coroutine).

If you're a competent C programmer, you might also let C do the work; e.g. call a C function, pass it a Lua callback function, and call the callback from a newly created pthread once the ping is complete.

Disclaimer: code is untested.